# Preserving formatting for special characters with printf

Tags: f#, printf

i switched to printf-style formatting from .net style ( {0}...) and noticed that formatting for special characters is not being preserved anymore. 
what's the technique for preserving formatting with printf?
i am doing something like `Printf.kprintf Log.Debug format`.

I understand that StringFormat makes literal strings (prenends a @"") but printf does not.

EDIT: 
I basically want to preserve formatting, like backslashes. if i am printing out a filepath, i want to see the "C:\Program Files..." unmolested, like StringFormat would print.

Comment: What special characters do you want to preserve? Can you add some example?

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of string literals in F#: normal string literals which look like `"string"` and verbatim string literals, which look like `@"string"`.  Either way, strings become instances of the .NET `System.String` type in memory, which are essentially just a sequence of `char` values.  If you want to create a string which contains certain characters such as backslashes, then you should escape them when using normal string literals: `"C:\\Program Files\\..."`, but you don't need to do this when using verbatim string literals: `@"C:\Program Files\..."`.  Either way, the the value in memory will consist of the characters 'C', ':', '\', 'P', 'r', etc.  You may find that forgetting to escape a backslash doesn't always cause problems, since backslashes are only interpreted as escape sequences when they precede particular characters (so you can get away with `"C:\Program Files"` but not `"C:\test"`).

Once the value is in memory, `String.Format` and the `printf` family of functions works in essentially the same way:

```
let sf1 = System.String.Format("{0}", "C:\\test")
let sf2 = System.String.Format("{0}", @"C:\test")
let pf1 = sprintf "%s" "C:\\test"
let pf2 = sprintf "%s" @"C:\test"
```

You'll find that all of these values are identical (and contain the backslashes in the right places).  Likewise:

```
let sf_bad = System.String.Format("{0}", "C:\test")
let pf_bad = sprintf "%s" "C:\test"
```

These are both the same, too, and both are mangled.

Note that `System.String.Format` doesn't undo the mangling that happened when the string literal was created - it has no way of knowing that the user didn't actually want a tab character embedded in the string.

Comment: yes, thank you, verbatim is the word i was looking for. is there a way to enumerate through the params to make string ones verbatim?

Comment: @Alex - I don't understand the question: "verbatim" only applies to the literal text that you are writing in your source code, it doesn't have any bearing on the values passed to a function at runtime.  Perhaps you could provide a complete example that's not behaving as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

The `printfn` family of functions print a string without any escaping if you use the `%s` format
(The `%s` format specifies that the argument is a string and should be printed as is):

```
> printfn "%s" "C:\\Test";;
C:\Test
val it : unit = ()
```

The behavior is different if you use `%A` (which specifies that the argument is any object and should be printed using the F# syntax - note that this works e.g. for lists). Although even this doesn't seem to escape `"` characters:

```
> printfn "%A" "C:\\Test";;
"C:\Test"
val it : unit = ()
```

Comment: that's not what i am looking for. you have already escaped the backslashes in your example and hence you are only seeing a single backslash in the output. i have input that has a single backslash and i want to see a single backslash in the output.

Comment: That has nothing to do with `printf`, and everything to do with how string literals work in a particular programming language.

Comment: What about `printfn "%A" @"C:\Test"`?